# Networking and wireless router help

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, windows-server-2003, router

I have 2 questions that I`ve been hitting my head on

We have a network with 24 users. The network is behind a sonic wall and are server is behind the sonic wall with the rest of the network

Are network address in the office is 192.168.52.x  Subnet 255.255.255.0 Gateway 192.168.52.1 and the dns is the server and gateway ip Server is 192.168.52.183

Everything is working fine but the owner wants to add a dlink dir601 wireless router to the network. I plug the router in the wall and then into the  owners computer  and everything works..

the router gives the computer a 192.168.0.100 ip and a gateway of 192.168.0.1

Everything works fine for awhile. But when the owners remotes into the server or if he is searching the web it boots her off for a couple of mins.. Why is this happening?

When the owner is disconnect from the router everything is perfect

Is there some sort of settings in the router that I need to configure? if so what?

Right now the sonic wall is acting as a dhcp server for now.. Are firewall hosting company will be changing this and we will be putting dhcp on the servers along with back up dc's

Thanks

Comment: Is there an issue where you can't implement a standard Wireless Access Point? like [this one](http://goo.gl/TR5mW) for example, I am not endorsing that wap. There is often issues when trying to add a 2nd router to an infrastructure and trying to use it as an AP.

Comment: Could you explain the network topology in a bit more details? What is the purpose of the DLink device (only need a WiFi Access Point or create a different subnet?) and how do you link it to _the owner's computer_ and the rest of the network (replace network-to-PC link or create a second one)?

Comment: this is how the network is configured. Cable modem---) sonic wall---) switch----)all the computers.. However the owners computer is now connected gateway-->sonicwall-->switch-->routers---pc.

Comment: the dlink is there so a few people can connect through wireless (2-3 laptops).. I`m guessing the dlink is pushing the owners computer to the 192.168.0.100 range... where the sonicwall is pushing everything else to the 192.169.52.1-254 range.. could this be the problem.. if so how would I fix it/

Comment: The owners PC is connect outside of your internal network i.e. outside of the sonicwall?

Comment: no there all in the same network.. if I unplug the router and connect the owners computer normally everything is good  I get a 192.168.52.92 ip

Comment: going into thee computer I see the following errors in the event viewer Your computer was not able to renew its address from the network (from the DHCP Server) for the Network Card with network address 0013206BFD05.  The following error occurred: 
The semaphore timeout period has expired. . Your computer will continue to try and obtain an address on its own from the network address (DHCP) server.



The IP address lease 192.168.0.100 for the Network Card with network address 0013206BFD05 has been denied by the DHCP server 192.168.0.1 (The DHCP Server sent a DHCPNACK message).